# Java: Combination of elements in array in couples

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I have an array of elements (even number) and I want to get all possible combinations of them in couples.

If the array is

```
String[] test = new String[4]; 
String[] test= {"e1","e2","e3","e4"};
```

The output should be:

```
Combination1 e1-e2 , e3-e4
Combination2 e1-e3 , e2-e4
Combination3 e1-e4 , e2-e3
Combination4 e4-e1 , e3-e2
Combination5 e3-e1 , e4-e2
Combination6 e2-e1 , e4-e3
```

Comment: pls show what u tried?

Comment: If you are after combinations then `e1-e2` is the same combination as `e2-e1` and there should only be 3 results output. If you are after permutations then they are not the same and there should be 24 results output (`e1-e2,e3-e4`, `e1-e2,e4-e3`, `e2-e1,e3-e4`, `e2-e1,e4-e3`, etc). Are you after permutations or combinations?

Comment: I've tried different 'for' loops but nothing worked as desired (i'm a beginner). 
I'm looking for permutations apparently, sorry about the misunderstanding. The ouput should be like the one I wrote in my question.

Comment: Edit (should have been 12 not 24): If you are after permutations then [...] there should be 12 results output (`e1-e2,e3-e4`, `e1-e2,e4-e3`, `e2-e1,e3-e4`, `e2-e1,e4-e3`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[<kbd>Link to previous answer</kbd>](http://pastie.org/8634227)

---

```
String[] test = {"e1","e2","e3","e4"};

for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

    for (int j = i + 1; j < test.length; j++) {

        System.out.print(test[i] + " - " + test[j]);

        boolean foundExtra = false;

        for (int k = 0; k < test.length && !foundExtra; k++)
        {
            if (k != j && k != i)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < test.length; l++)
                {
                    if (l != k && l != j && l != i)
                    {
                        System.out.println(" , " + test[k] + " - " + test[l]);
                        foundExtra = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will give the output:

```java
e1 - e2 , e3 - e4
e1 - e3 , e2 - e4
e1 - e4 , e2 - e3
e2 - e3 , e1 - e4
e2 - e4 , e1 - e3
e3 - e4 , e1 - e2
```

This is not the output you put in your question, but I believe this is the output you want, judging from your sports teams comment.

**Don't be scared of the loops** - I did this in one try because I thought threw it easily.

What I was thinking: Find all of the combinations, like in my previous answer. That's what I started with. Next thing I did (the last 2 of 4 loops - `k` and `l`), was check for the *other* teams that were left.

So cycle through all of the elements, check if `i` and `j` were not already used, then that was `k`. Then, cycle through all of the elements again, check if `i`, `j`, and `k` were not already used, then that was `l`.

Comment: Thanks, that was almost the same as the one I tried excluding i!=j check. Now the problem is how to group them in couples without element repetition.

Comment: I mean repetition of elements in group of permutations. Like in your output permutation 1 can be grouped only with permutation 5 or permutation 8. It's like a sports championship, each group of 2 permutations represents a round where every team has to play with another one. The ouput has to show all the rounds. (every teams plays another one twice on home and away basis hence the permutation and not combination apparently)

Comment: You sir are the real MVP. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Write two `for` loops :

```
for (int i =0; i < test.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < test.length; j++) {
       // code to print a[i] - a[j]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for an array of any even number of elements (and is generic so should work for other things than strings as well):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Q2112634 {

    public static class Pair<X> {
        final X first;
        final X second;

        public Pair( final X one, final X two){
            first = one;
            second = two;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return first.toString() + "-" + second.toString(); 
        }

        public String toReverseString(){
            return second.toString() + "-" + first.toString(); 
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <X> void getCombinations( final ArrayList<Pair<X>[]> combinations, final LinkedList<Pair<X>> pairs, final LinkedList<X> list ) {
//      System.out.println(list.size());
        final X first = list.removeFirst();
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i ) {
            final X second = list.remove( i );
            final Pair<X> p = new Pair<X>( first, second );
            pairs.addLast( p );
            if ( list.size() == 0 )
            {
                combinations.add( pairs.toArray( (Pair[]) Array.newInstance( p.getClass(), pairs.size() ) ) );
            }
            else
            {
                getCombinations( combinations, pairs, list );
            }
            list.add( i, second );
            pairs.removeLast();
        }
        list.addFirst( first );
    }

    static <E> String arrayToString( E[] arr ) {
        if ( arr.length == 0 )
            return "";
        final StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        str.append( arr[0].toString() );
        for ( int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i )
        {
            str.append( ',' );
            str.append( arr[i].toString() );
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = { "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4" };

        int num_combinations = 1;
        for ( int i = test.length - 1; i > 1; i = i - 2 )
            num_combinations *= i;

        final ArrayList<Pair<String>[]> combinations = new ArrayList<Pair<String>[]>( num_combinations );
        final LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
        for ( String s : test )
            strings.add( s );

        getCombinations( combinations, new LinkedList<Pair<String>>(), strings );

        System.out.println( "-----Combinations-----" );
        int i = 1;
        for ( Pair<String>[] combination: combinations ){
            System.out.println( "Combination " + (i++) + " " + arrayToString( combination ) );
        }

        System.out.println( "-----Permutations-----" );
        i = 1;
        for ( Pair<String>[] combination: combinations ){
            for ( int j = 0; j < Math.pow( 2, combination.length ); ++j )
            {
                System.out.print( "Permutation " + (i++) + " " );
                for ( int k = 0; k < combination.length; ++k )
                {
                    if ( k > 0 )
                        System.out.print(',');
                    if ( (j & ( (int) Math.pow( 2, k ) ) ) == 0 )
                        System.out.print( combination[k].toString() );
                    else
                        System.out.print( combination[k].toReverseString() );
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
-----Combinations-----
Combination 1 e1-e2,e3-e4
Combination 2 e1-e3,e2-e4
Combination 3 e1-e4,e2-e3
-----Permutations-----
Permutation 1 e1-e2,e3-e4
Permutation 2 e2-e1,e3-e4
Permutation 3 e1-e2,e4-e3
Permutation 4 e2-e1,e4-e3
Permutation 5 e1-e3,e2-e4
Permutation 6 e3-e1,e2-e4
Permutation 7 e1-e3,e4-e2
Permutation 8 e3-e1,e4-e2
Permutation 9 e1-e4,e2-e3
Permutation 10 e4-e1,e2-e3
Permutation 11 e1-e4,e3-e2
Permutation 12 e4-e1,e3-e2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String[] test= {"e1","e2","e3","e4"};
int count=1;
for(int i=0; i<test.length/2; i++)
    for(int k=0, j=0; k<test.length; k++,j++) {
        if(i==k) k++; if(j==i+test.length/2) j++;
        System.out.print("Permutatation "+count+": ");
        System.out.println(test[i]+"-"+test[k]+", "+test[i+test.length/2]+"-"+test[j]);
        count++;
    }
```

Output:

```
Permutatation 1: e1-e2, e3-e1
Permutatation 2: e1-e3, e3-e2
Permutatation 3: e1-e4, e3-e4
Permutatation 4: e2-e1, e4-e1
Permutatation 5: e2-e3, e4-e2
Permutatation 6: e2-e4, e4-e3
```